# Default argument with *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python newbie here. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) have an example for `OrderedDict` usage:

```
class LRU(OrderedDict):
    'Limit size, evicting the least recently looked-up key when full'

    def __init__(self, maxsize=128, /, *args, **kwds):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
```

What is the `/` in the `__init__` method signature?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters